# Issue when dynamically setting properties using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have a task where object properties need to be populated from data received via JSON web service. The property names are mapped to the JSON keys. I am using the following code in an attempt to populate the object but the app crashes when it hits this line:

```
        while(looper.hasNext()){
            String key = looper.next();
            String val = json.get(key).toString();
            user.getClass().getDeclaredField(key).set(user, val); // crash
        }
```

The object is called user. I have verified that the key variable does match a property in the user object. Any ideas on how to fix this? THanks!

Comment: Not sure if you're aware of Gson. It does what you're trying to do and it works really well. I highly recommend checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should set your field accessible

```
Field field = user.getClass().getDeclaredField(key);
if (field != null) {
 field.setAccessible(true);
 field.set(user, val);
}
```

Comment: The accessible stuff is needed if the field is private/protected/package (i.e. not public), but the more likely situation is that getDeclaredField(key) is returning null since the key doesn't exist - blackbelt's code will handle that too, though!